# A NSDictionary with some repeat keys

Tags: iphone, cocoa, json, nsdictionary

I got a `NSDictionary` like this after convert `JSON` to `NSDictionary`:

```
content=(
     {}
         )
content=(
     {}
         )
content=(
     {}
         )
```

I want to pick up data in each 'content' field, but I found whatever I did (by using all keys, objectforkey, keynumerator) the Xcode always told me `terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'`. I think it's not reasonable to create a nsdictionary with repeat keys,but i need to solve the problem in my project.

the code:

```
{
    "adv_name" = "\U767d\U677f";
    page =     (
                {
            content =             (
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U56fe\U7247";
                },
                                {
                    content = 3;
                    type = "\U6587\U5b57";
                },
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U89c6\U9891";
                }
            );
            "content_count" = 3;
        },
                {
            content =             (
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U56fe\U7247";
                },
                                {
                    content = 2;
                    type = "\U6587\U5b57";
                },
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U89c6\U9891";
                }
            );
            "content_count" = 3;
        },
                {
            content =             (
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U56fe\U7247";
                },
                                {
                    content = "";
                    type = "\U89c6\U9891";
                },
                                {
                    content = 12;
                    type = "\U6587\U5b57";
                }
            );
            "content_count" = 3;
        }
    );
    "page_count" = 3;
}
```

I've found the solution using `objectEnumerator`.

Comment: It seems like your NSDictionary is not what you think it is. There is probably something wrong with your parsing and assignment. You need to rewrite your question, and include some code.

Comment: I need to see some code before I can say anything for definite, but this looks like an `NSDictionary` in an `NSArray` if these are your log messages. Can't say more though without additional code.

Comment: That's no objective-c code. But if you have found the answer yourself, please close this question.

Comment: In future, when you want to ask about an exception, you need to include the actual exception message, copy and pasted (do not summarize), in your question. Also, when you find the solution yourself, please post it in an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is a "description" dump of the object.  What you've got is a dictionary (NSDictionary) containing entries "adv_name", "page", and "page_count".

The dictionary entry "page" contains an array (NSArray) of 3 dictionaries.

Each of the 3 dictionaries contains an array of 3 more dictionaries in the "content" entry.

The innermost dictionaries contain entries "content" and "type".